# Clojurescript react-with-addons and bootstrap-cljs

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, reactjs, clojurescript

I want to use in my app both `react-with-addons` (to allow css transitionsm as per https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/animation.html) and [`bootstrap-cljs`](https://github.com/luxbock/bootstrap-cljs) (so I can use bootstrap components).

The problem is that when in my code I call a bootstrap function, I get in the browser an error: `ReactBootstrap is not defined`.

It seems to me that the problem is that in order to use `react-with-addons` I had exclude the regular react package in my `project.clj`: `[org.omcljs/om "0.9.0" :exclusions [cljsjs/react]]`.

Am I correct? Is there a way around it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out I had a conflict of version. I was using `react-with-addons` v0.12, while `bootstrap-cljs` requires React version > 0.14. Upgrading my `react-with-addons` solved the issue.